# Safety of MTLTexture reuse across MTLCommandQueues

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

Does Metal's built-in hazard tracking (`MTLHazardTrackingMode.tracked`) ensure that writing a texture from one command queue does not collide with usage of that same texture on a different command queue, or do I need to synchronize this access manually? My context is conceptually similar to [this unanswered question](https://developers.apple.com/forums/thread/652633) on the Apple developer forum, where one "writer" queue is handling textures at a potentially different rate than a "reader" queue which renders the results.

Comment: This and your other new question are infinitely more answerable than your first post. As for my "tone", I was just trying to help so your questions have a much better chance of being answered which I think they do now.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate the intent. Just wanted to note that the delivery could be improved. StackOverflow generally comes across as pretty hostile toward question-askers. For what it's worth, the questions in my original post were highly related, and I do believe an answer tying them together would have been valuable for others. However, I can accept that StackOverflow might not be the place for holistic and more nuanced explanations.

Comment: SO etiquette is supposed to be direct to the point without the fluff. It was a very long and complicated question asking five different things. I have no doubt it would have been closed. It doesn't matter if they are related; if you ask more than one question you are violating SO rules and good chance it will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `MTLHazardTrackingMode.tracked` ensures that writing a texture from one command queue does not interfere with usage on a different command queue, but it can cause delays.

From Apple's Documentation:

> If you submit a command that modifies the resource, Metal delays that command from executing until prior commands accessing that resource are complete, and prevents future commands from executing until the modifications are complete.

For optimal performance you would want to synchronize manually, Apple adds:

> For better performance, use untracked resources and synchronize access yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I did see this documentation, but I couldn't find any explicit mention of safety across different queues, only within the same queue across multiple command buffers. I suppose the "any" in "Metal tracks dependencies on any accesses to the resource" should imply what I want, but I've learned you can never be too careful when dealing with Apple documentation. Do you happen to know of any references explicitly mentioning hazard tracking across different queues?

Comment: Note for future viewers: the recommendation to synchronize resource access manually for better performance is given in the context of a `MTLHeap`, not in general. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlhazardtrackingmode/tracked

Comment: It actually says for resources, not heaps: "For better performance, use untracked `resources` and synchronize access yourself."

Comment: In addition to the word "any", no where in the documentation does it state that hazard tracking only works in the same queue. So in my mind it is the same as stating it should work across different queues.

Comment: Right, but in the context of that whole paragraph it's talking about resources that belong to a heap. It's saying that it's better to use manual synchronization if you're going to use a heap, because using automatic tracking on heap resources causes synchronization on the entire heap rather than only the resource in question.

Comment: I realize it's part of the same paragraph but they specifically use the word `resource` which leads me to believe they should have added a line return. I also think manually managing resources will be more efficient than automatically managing them.